# Distance Between 1-D Histograms and Binning

Tags: distance, histogram, binning

In order to calculate the distance between two 1-D histograms, they must have the same number of bins. I'm wondering if it's preferable to have more or fewer bins for such calculation.

For example, suppose the Freedman-Diaconis estimator (or another estimator, e.g., Sturges' rule) yields a histogram `A` with 9 bins and a histogram `B` with 8 bins. I'd like to calculate the Jensen-Shannon distance between them. Should I increase the number of bins of histogram `A` to 9, or decrease the number of bins of `B` to 8? By "increasing" or "decreasing" the number of bins I mean recomputing the histograms with the new number of bins. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The meaning of "preferable" depends on the objectives of your calculation: what is the purpose?

Comment: The overall goal is to check the extent that two distributions change with time. And by "preferable" I mean if there's perhaps a correct or more theoretically sound way of thinking about the binning approach.

Comment: Then don't use histograms!  Edit your post to ask the question you really need answered.

Comment: Well, I guess I wouldn't need to get histograms specifically as density estimators and then calculate their distance. Maybe a two-sample KS test would do.

Comment: Specially since the data are continuous anyway.